# Run stable baselines with limited memory

Tags: stable-baselines

I am trying to train a SAC agent with stable baselines over an environment (Walker2d from mujoco) fam for 5M time steps.

```
model = SAC("MlpPolicy", env, verbose=1, **hyperparam)
save_every = 5000000
model.learn(total_timesteps=save_every, log_interval=save_every//10,)
```

However, this procedure suffers from a memory leak since SAC is saving something at every step, and the memory keeps growing and growing. Is there a way to tell stable baselines to limit the memory used?

Comment: I am experiencing a similar issue on PPO and A2C as well which feels similar to the issue described here (https://github.com/hill-a/stable-baselines/issues/182) but this was for stable_bselines3's predecesor, "stable_baselines". Are you using a custom environment? Shooting darts in the dark here, but I am wondering if maybe new "generated" environments may not be closing properly.

Answer (score 0):

You may check whether you have .append(), or sth like this kind of codes. And close the log, tensorboard that will record.